# Django: how apply uuid django.contrib.auth migration

Tags: python, django

I create a project Django with Postgres.
I only apply to `User` model.
But I want to use uuid for field primary key `id` in all models in app `django.contrib.auth` such as `User`, `Permission`, `Group` ...

Beside, I want to apply uuid for all migrations of my project

How can I do that, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a specific setting to do this, except by using

```
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
```

in each model you define. More info [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield)

On the other hand, you can create your own model base class, which can be extended by all other models you will create.

```
class MyBaseModel(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

class MyConcreteModel(MyBaseModel):
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I try this, but it working well with model created by myself.
It's not working models of `django.contrib.auth` app